# Signalr running behind Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, signalr

I have really no knowledge on how to configure signalr of back-end server on Nginx box. I did lot of googling tried those but did not work so any information/help would be greatly welcomed.

Nginx server : https://20.20.20.20/
Backend server : http://10.10.10.10/

I have configured Nginx as reverse proxy on windows server 2012. I have configured my back-end server on Nginx server using the below mentioned configuration file.
So my proxy is working absolutely fine. Whenever client hits the Nginx it redirects call to the backend server.

The problem currently that I am facing is my client wants to connect to the backend server for signalr communication. The client(mobile app) uses login server details to connect the signalr, in the normal workflow the login server and signalr both are same but incase of reverse proxy the login server is actually Nginx so it is trying to connect to Nginx and failing to connect.

Are there any setting that we can make at Nginx to pass through signalr calls made by client.

My configuration below

```
 server {
    listen   443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl_certificate      "E:/Cer15/nginx.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key  "E:/Cer15/nginx.key";

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10/mywebservice;
    }

}
```

Thanks,
Vinod